# How to extract only valid equations from a string

Tags: r, regex

Extract all the valid equations in the following text.

I have tried a few regex expressions but none seem to work.
Hoping to use `sub` or `gsub` functions in R.

```
myText <- 'equation1: 2+3=5, equation2 is: 2*3=6, do not extract 2w3=6'
expected result : 2+3=5  2*3=6
```

Comment: Do you also want to capture something like `2w*3=6`?

Comment: why isn't `3=6` valid ? because it's not preceded by a space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach.  We can use `grepexpr()` to find multiple matches of equations in the input string:

```
x <- c("equation1: 2+3=5, equation2 is: 2*3=6, do not extract 2w3=6")
m <- gregexpr("\\b\\w+(?:[+-\\*]\\w+)+=\\w+\\b", x)
regmatches(x, m)

[[1]]
[1] "2+3=5" "2*3=6"
```

Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
\\b\\w+           match an initial symbol
(?:[+-\\*]\\w+)   then match at least one arithmetic symbol (+-\*) followed
                  by another variable

+=\\w+            match an equals sign, followed by a variable
```

Comment: Do you only want to capture equations with all numbers, or do you only want to capture equations which have symbols like `+-/*`?

Comment: what you did was sufficient.

Comment: thank you for the response! have a great day (or night) depending where youre from. lol

Answer (score 0):

For the examples you've posted, the regex `(\d+[+\-*\/]\d+=\d+)` should extract the equations and not the rest of the text. Note that this regex does not handle variables/variable names, only numbers and the basic arithmetic operators. This may need to be adapted for `r`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N103kz/1/)